# Excel: Adding a Criteria Check into a Countifs dynamically, based on the contents of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs, sumproduct

First time asking, long time reading! Any help would be much appreciated.

I have an excel sheet with two cells that contain values from a drop down list - let's call these condition1Cell and condition2Cell. The options available in the drop downs for the cells can either be: **A, B, or Total** (where total is both A & B) for condition1Cell; and **X, Y, Z or Total** (where total is X, Y and Z) for condition2Cell; meaning in total I can have up to 12 different scenarios depending on a users selection.

Depending on a users selection, I want to aggregate data from a data sheet according to their selection i.e. if the user selects A and X, I want to aggregate the data only where the conditions of A & X are met; if the user selects Total and Z, I want to aggregate the data only where the conditions are Total (A&B) and Z. The user can change the selections in real time and I want the sheet to update the numbers as they make the changes.

To aggregate the data, I will be using COUNTIFS,SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT functions, and for when non-total selections are made these work well.

e.g. *=COUNTIFS(CriteriaRng1,"A",CriteriaRng2,"X")*  (1)

However, when I want to aggregate the data when a 'Total' selection is made, this is when I have problems. The formula:

*=COUNTIFS(CriteriaRng1,"A",CriteriaRng2,"Total")*   (2)

will not work, as the underlying data column does no have Total as an option, only X,Y & Z. Now one way to get round this would be to enclose the COUNTIF within a large IF statement:

e.g *=IF(AND(Condition1Cell = "A", Condition2Cell = "Total", COUNTIFS(CriteriaRng1,"A",CriteriaRng2,"X",CriteriaRng3,"Y",CriteriaRng4,"Z"),IF(....* etc.   (3)

But given I can have 12 different scenarios in total, and the number of scenarios may increase in the future, this would be a very painful nested IF statement. Is there any way I can enclose conditional criteria checks within the aggregate function itself, so that when a total is selected, the criteria is not applied within the aggregate function (i.e. the CriteriaRng2 check in (2) above is only applied when the Condition2Cell is not "Total")?

I feel like there must be a way of doing this, but despite my best searching I cannot seem to find a solution. I am happy to do this with Array formulas if required.

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: Assuming the cells are never blank, you could use `"*"` as the criterion for `Total` as it will match any value.

Comment: Are there any other items, for example, in CriteriaRng2 than X, Y and Z?.  If not, you could just use `COUNTA` for total.  And if you are `OR`ing the criteria, you'll need to `SUM` the different `COUNTIF` results. When they are separate criteria, as you show, they will be `AND`'d

Comment: Thank you @Rory for your quickly reply. Using asterisk solves the issue as I can use asterisk as the drop-down option instead of the word '"TOTAL"'.

Comment: Thank you @RonRosenfeld for your reply but I have decided to go with Rory's answer.